# Coredata: Convert NSString column to NSDate in predicate and Compare

Tags: ios, core-data

Hi I am developing an IOS application. In which the dates are stored in String column type in core data entity. Now I want to get some filtered records based on date. But the problem is that the date is saved as String not as NSDate object in coredata.

My Question is that is there a way to convert String in Nsdate and compare it with the NSDate object and get the greater and smaller dates. I want something like in MYSQL query where you can use "DATE()" function of MySQL and convert a String to Date and compare it with any date.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Certainly not without loading everything into memory to make the conversion, and `NSPredicate` doesn't deal with that level of code (unless perhaps you add a category on `NSString` so you can have a single method to call to make the conversion).

The obvious solution is to store the dates as dates instead of strings, then everything will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can by creating a category on your NSManagedObject subclass  and create a function that can convert your nsstring date into a nsdate . Then you could compare that in an NSPredicate.